# Getting CPU temperature using Python?

Tags: python, cpu, temperature

How do I retrieve the temperature of my CPU using Python?  (Assuming I'm on Linux)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Py-cputemp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py-cputemp/) seems to do the job.

Comment: py-cputemp is basically a thin veneer over /proc/acpi/thermal_zone.  This originally didn't work for me until I realized that I needed to enable ACPI in my BIOS.  I had disabled it because I figured I didn't want power management on a server.  Thanks for the answer; I'm accepting this one because it was posted first and lead me to think about the source of my problem.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: This library is unmaintained and isn't even registered in PyPI...

Comment: Plus there are no instructions here as to how it is used.

Comment: I prefer gpiozero
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature, LoadAverage

cpu = CPUTemperature()
print ("CPU temperature is %s" % cpu.temperature)
load = LoadAverage()
print ("CPU temperature is %s" % load.load_average)

Comment: try "sensors -j"

Answer (score 23):

There is a [newer "sysfs thermal zone" API](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/kernel/sysfs-thermal-zone.html) (see also [LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/268958/) and [Linux kernel doc](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/thermal/sysfs-api.txt)) showing temperatures under e.g.

```
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

Readings are in thousandths of degrees Celcius (although in older kernels, it may have just been degrees C).

Answer (score 20):

I recently implemented this in [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/#sensors) for Linux only.

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.sensors_temperatures()
{'acpitz': [shwtemp(label='', current=47.0, high=103.0, critical=103.0)],
 'asus': [shwtemp(label='', current=47.0, high=None, critical=None)],
 'coretemp': [shwtemp(label='Physical id 0', current=52.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
              shwtemp(label='Core 0', current=45.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
              shwtemp(label='Core 1', current=52.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
              shwtemp(label='Core 2', current=45.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
              shwtemp(label='Core 3', current=47.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0)]}
```

Answer (score 8):

If your Linux supports ACPI, reading pseudo-file `/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THM0/temperature` (the path may differ, I know it's `/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/temperature` in some systems) should do it.  But I don't think there's a way that works in *every* Linux system in the world, so you'll have to be more specific about exactly what Linux you have!-)

Answer (score 7):

Reading files in **/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/temp1_*** worked for me but AFAIK there are no standards for doing this cleanly.
Anyway, you can try this and make sure it provides the same number of CPUs shown by "**sensors**" cmdline utility, in which case you can assume it's reliable.

```
from __future__ import division
import os
from collections import namedtuple


_nt_cpu_temp = namedtuple('cputemp', 'name temp max critical')

def get_cpu_temp(fahrenheit=False):
    """Return temperatures expressed in Celsius for each physical CPU
    installed on the system as a list of namedtuples as in:

    >>> get_cpu_temp()
    [cputemp(name='atk0110', temp=32.0, max=60.0, critical=95.0)]
    """
    # http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/hwmon/sysfs-interface
    cat = lambda file: open(file, 'r').read().strip()
    base = '/sys/class/hwmon/'
    ls = sorted(os.listdir(base))
    assert ls, "%r is empty" % base
    ret = []
    for hwmon in ls:
        hwmon = os.path.join(base, hwmon)
        label = cat(os.path.join(hwmon, 'temp1_label'))
        assert 'cpu temp' in label.lower(), label
        name = cat(os.path.join(hwmon, 'name'))
        temp = int(cat(os.path.join(hwmon, 'temp1_input'))) / 1000
        max_ = int(cat(os.path.join(hwmon, 'temp1_max'))) / 1000
        crit = int(cat(os.path.join(hwmon, 'temp1_crit'))) / 1000
        digits = (temp, max_, crit)
        if fahrenheit:
            digits = [(x * 1.8) + 32 for x in digits]
        ret.append(_nt_cpu_temp(name, *digits))
    return ret
```

Answer (score 4):

Look after `pyspectator` in `pip`

> Requires python3

```
from pyspectator import Cpu
from time import sleep
cpu = Cpu(monitoring_latency=1)

while True:
    print (cpu.temperature)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: I tried the code you provided but first of all the import seems to be 
from pyspectator.processor import Cpu
and if it's python3 as the warning says the print command should use brackets.. anyway this dont work for me the cpu.load is displayed correctly but the temperature is always None :(

Comment: 16.04 LTS seems not to like this import.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your Linux distro, you may find a file under `/proc` that contains this information. For example, [this page](http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/CPU_Temperature.html) suggests `/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THM/temperature`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can install the lm-sensors package, then install [PySensors](https://bitbucket.org/blackjack/pysensors/overview) (a python binding for libsensors).

Comment: Unfortunately PySensors only runs under Python 2.x version

Answer (score 1):

Sysmon works nice. Nicely made, it does much more than measure CPU temperature. It is a command line program, and logs all the data it measured to a file. Also, it is open-source and written in python 2.7.

Sysmon: https://github.com/calthecoder/sysmon-1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [PyI2C](http://pyi2c.sourceforge.net/) module, it can read directly from the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I would reflect on **SDsolar**'s solving above, modified the code a bit., and now it shows not only one value. Until the while loop you gets continuously the actual value of the CPUs temperature

On linux systems:

**Install the pyspectator module:**

```
pip install pyspectator
```

**Put this code into a file 'cpu-temp.py'**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pyspectator.processor import Cpu
from time import sleep

while True:
    cpu = Cpu(monitoring_latency=1) #changed here
    print (cpu.temperature)
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Linux systems(Tried on Ubuntu 18.04)**

Install the [acpi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ACPI_modules) module by
`sudo apt install acpi`

Running `acpi -V`  should give you a ton of info about your system. Now we just need to get the temperature value via python.

```
import os
os.system("acpi -V > output.txt")
battery = open("output.txt", "r")
info = battery.readline()
val = info.split()
percent4real = val[3]
percentage = int(percent4real[:-1])
print(percentage)
```

The `percentage` variable will give you the temperature.
So, first we take the output of the `acpi -V` command in a text file and then read it. We need to convert it into an integer since the data is all in String type.

- Note: This command does not display CPU temperature when used in WSL

Comment: The approach is good, but you extract the battery percentage - at least on my Ubuntu-system, where the first line of output from `acpi`is `Battery 0: Full, 100%`.

Comment: Ah my bad, I confused two questions. I'll change it later with regards to the CPU temperature, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Additionally, please make sure to obtain the CPU temperature. It seems that maybe this is the battery temperature, but I'm not sure.