# How can I get the CPU temperature in Python?

Tags: python, cpu, temperature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting CPU temperature using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440511/getting-cpu-temperature-using-python)

What is the simplest method of going about this? Also preferably in Celsius.

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440511/getting-cpu-temperature-using-python

Answer (score 5):

There's no standard Python library for this, but on various platforms you may be able to use a Python bridge to a platform API to access this information.

For example on Windows this is available through the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) APIs, which are available to Python through the [PyWin32 library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). There is even a [Python WMI library](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) which wraps PyWin32 to provide a more convenient interface. To get the temperature you'll need to use one of these libraries to access the root/WMI namespace and the MSAcpi_ThermalZone Temperature class. This gives the temperature in tenths of a Kelvin, so you'll need to convert to Celsius by deducting 2732 and dividing by 10.

Not sure about about Linux or Mac I'm afraid, but there may be equivalent libraries you can use. A quick Google indicated that /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THM/temperature may be what yoiu're after if your distro supports the proc virtual filesystem for accessing kernel information.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, that info is in /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/