# Which python module is used to read CPU temperature and processor fan speed in Windows?

Tags: python, wmi

Which python module is used to read CPU temperature and processor Fan speed in Windows?

I explored the WMI python module, however I am unable to find the correct option or function to capture the above mentioned info.

Actually I tried the following code snip, but it returns 'nothing'.

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI()
print w.Win32_TemperatureProbe()[0].CurrentReading
```

Is there a way to get this information?

Comment: Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440511/getting-cpu-temperature-using-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262603/accessing-cpu-temperature-in-python

Comment: This only works when run as administrator [http://stackoverflow.com/a/33905500/3500406](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33905500/3500406)

Answer (score 3):

As per [Microsoft's MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Most of the information that the Win32_TemperatureProbe WMI class
>   provides comes from SMBIOS. Real-time readings for the CurrentReading
>   property cannot be extracted from SMBIOS tables. **For this reason,
>   current implementations of WMI do not populate the CurrentReading
>   property**. The CurrentReading property's presence is reserved for
>   future use.

You can use `MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature` instead:

```
import wmi

w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\\wmi")
print (w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0].CurrentTemperature/10.0)-273.15
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is it possible to read CPU - FAN SPEED using python..?

Comment: I get a bunch of "unexpected" OLE/COM exceptions when I try doing this, why might that be?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

```
import wmi

w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\\wmi")
print (w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0].CurrentTemperature / 10.0) - 273.15
```

Make sure you're running the program as administrator, otherwise it will fail or give error codes when trying to test/run/execute your code.