# Get CPU temperature in python on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, wmi, cpu, temperature

Basically, I want to read the CPU temperature with Python. Please explain in layman's terms as I have never done this on Windows before nor have I had to work with `wmi`.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\wmi")
temperature_info = w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0]
print temperature_info.CurrentTemperature
```

(I got this code from this thread: [Accessing CPU temperature in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262603/accessing-cpu-temperature-in-python))

However, on running the script, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SerialSystemMonitor", line 4, in <module>
    temperature_info = w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 819, in query
    handle_com_error ()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
    raise klass (com_error=err)
x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217396, 'OLE error 0x8004100c', None, None)>
```

What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MSDN page on [WMI Error Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394559(v=vs.85).aspx), the error you have received is:

> **WBEM_E_NOT_SUPPORTED**
> 2147749900 (0x8004100C)
>
> Feature or operation is not supported.

Presumably, then, your CPU does not provide temperature information through WMI. If your CPU doesn't expose this information, you're probably out of luck, at least as far as a straightforward solution in Python goes.

I assume you've tried the other option given in the answer you linked, using `Win32_TemperatureProbe()`; if you haven't, try it.

Comment: I have indeed tried that. I guess python isn't really the best language to use so i am going to try C++. Please check out the thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060944/get-temperature-in-c-with-core-temp-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Just execute as Admin. It's work for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10325220)

Comment: @JamesKPolk I don't agree. I have no idea whether this solves the problem, or even makes sense, but I think this is a valid answer. If it turns out to be wrong, it should be downvoted, not flagged.