# How to set a maximum core temperature for my processor while executing a python script?

Tags: python, temperature

In order to protect my PC's components while a running a script that needs a lot of processing (and heats the computer), how can i set a maximum temperature for my processor, if there is such thing?

Comment: [Getting CPU temperature using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440511/getting-cpu-temperature-using-python) and on [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612215/how-to-set-a-maximum-core-temperature-for-my-processor-while-executing-a-python)

Comment: but, as mentioned, i need to no only read it, but keep my processor from going over a certain temperature while running my script

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at downloading Speedfan, which allows you to monitor several different component's temperature. If I'm not mistaken, you can set a max temperature for a particular component, which should help with your problem: http://download.cnet.com/SpeedFan/3000-2094_4-10067444.html.